# Can't insert Symbols like '€' in MySQL using PHP/PDO

Tags: apache2.4, php-5.6, mysql-5.7

I am trying to insert some data in my database table but I am getting this exception, when I am trying to save the € Euro symbol in the currency column:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 
Incorrect string value:  '\x80' for column 'currency' at row 1
```

If I don't use any symbols it is working fine. No exception is thrown and the data is written correctly in the database table.

That is the technology stack I am using:

- PHP  5.6.16
- MySQL 5.7
- Apache 2.4
- PDO (instead of mysqli)

I have tried to google a solution, but nothing worked for me:

- I tried to change the character set of my database, tables and columns to UTF8mb4
- I made configuration changes to character sets in my php.ini
- I tried it with mysqli and maysql instead of PDO
- I have wrote "charset=utf8mb4" in the connection String of the PDO object

But nothing was helpful...

This is the create script of my table, I am using at the moment:

```
CREATE TABLE `cars` (
`car_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`brand` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`model` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`car_trim` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`model_year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`car_condition` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`car_type` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`currency` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, <-- Where the € should be
PRIMARY KEY (`xy`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4   
COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

My PDO connection looks like this:

```
    if(!isset(self::$connection)) {
      try {
        self::$connection = new PDO('mysql:host='.self::$config['host'].
                                 ';dbname='.self::$config['dbname'].
                                 ';port='.self::$config['port'].
                                 ';charset='.self::$config['charset'], //utf8mb4
                                 self::$config['username'], 
                                 self::$config['password']
                               );
        self::$connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,  
                                         PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
      } catch (PDOException $e) {
        self::$logger->LogError('Connection.php: ' . $e->getMessage());
        echo $e->getMessage();
        self::$connection->rollBack();
        $this->closeConnection();
  }
}
```

The PHP code with the insert statement:

```
$db = new Db();

$car = new Car($_POST['carBrand'], $_POST['carModel'], $_POST['carTrim'],    
$_POST['carModelYear'], $_POST['carCondition'],
$_POST['carType'], $_POST['carFuelType'], $_POST['carTransmission'],  
$_POST['carEngine'], $_POST['carCylinder'],
$_POST['carMileage'], $_POST['carExteriorColor'],  
$_POST['carInteriorColor'], $_POST['carLocation'], $_POST['carVin'],
$_POST['carDriveTrain'], $_POST['carStock'], $_POST['carPrice'], 
$_POST['carPriceDetails'], $_POST['carCurrency'],
$_POST['carTax'], $_POST['carTaxDetails'], $_POST['carDescr'], 
$_POST['carBodyDescr'], $_POST['carDriveTrainDescr'],
$_POST['carExteriorDescr'], $_POST['carElectronicsDescr'],  
$_POST['carSaftyFeaturesDescr'], $_POST['carSpecialFeaturesDescr'],
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 'Edi', 'Edi', 
(empty($_POST['carOnline'])) ? 'off' : 'on');

$car_insertStm = 'INSERT INTO cardealer.cars ( ' . 
'brand, model,car_trim,model_year,car_condition,car_type, fuel_type, transmission, ' .
'car_engine, cylinder, mileage, exterior_color, interior_color, location, vin, drive_train, ' . 
'stock, price, price_descr, currency, tax, tax_descr, car_descr_long, body_descr, ' . 
drive_train_descr, exterior_descr, electronics_descr, safty_features_descr, special_features_descr, car_pic_1, car_pic_2, car_pic_3, ' . 
'car_pic_4, car_pic_5, car_pic_6, car_pic_7, car_pic_8, car_pic_9, car_pic_10, create_user, ' . 
'change_user, car_online ) ' .
'VALUES ( :brand, :model, :car_trim, :model_year, :car_condition, :car_type,  :fuel_type, :transmission, :car_engine, :cylinder, ' .
':mileage, :exterior_color, :interior_color, :location, :vin, :drive_train, 
:stock, :price, :price_descr, :currency, :tax, :tax_descr, ' .
':car_descr_long, :body_descr, :drive_train_descr, :exterior_descr, 
:electronics_descr, :safty_features_descr, :special_features_descr, ' .
':car_pic_1, :car_pic_2, :car_pic_3, :car_pic_4, :car_pic_5, :car_pic_6, 
:car_pic_7, :car_pic_8, :car_pic_9, :car_pic_10, :create_user, ' .
':change_user, :online ) ';

$pStatement = $db->getConnection()->prepare($car_insertStm);

$pStatement->bindParam(':brand', $_POST['carBrand'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pStatement->bindParam(':model', $_POST['carModel'], PDO::PARAM_STR);         
$pStatement->bindParam(':car_trim', $_POST['carTrim'], PDO::PARAM_STR);         
$pStatement->bindParam(':model_year',            
                        $_POST['carModelYear'],PDO::PARAM_INT);         
$pStatement->bindParam(':car_condition', 
                        $_POST['carCondition'], PDO::PARAM_STR);         
$pStatement->bindParam(':car_type', $_POST['carType'], PDO::PARAM_STR);         
$pStatement->bindParam(':fuel_type', $_POST['carFuelType'], PDO::PARAM_STR);        
$pStatement->bindParam(':transmission', 
                        $_POST['carTransmission'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pStatement->bindParam(':car_engine', $_POST['carEngine'], PDO::PARAM_STR);             
$pStatement->bindParam(':cylinder', $_POST['carCylinder'], PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$pStatement->bindParam(':mileage', $_POST['carMileage'],PDO::PARAM_INT);        
$pStatement->bindParam(':exterior_color', 
                        $_POST['carExteriorColor'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$pStatement->bindParam(':interior_color', 
                        $_POST['carInteriorColor'], PDO::PARAM_STR);     
$pStatement->bindParam(':location', $_POST['carLocation'], PDO::PARAM_STR);     
$pStatement->bindParam(':vin', $_POST['carVin'], PDO::PARAM_STR );          
$pStatement->bindParam(':drive_train', 
                        $_POST['carDriveTrain'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pStatement->bindParam(':stock', $_POST['carStock'], PDO::PARAM_STR);           
$pStatement->bindParam(':price', $_POST['carPrice'], PDO::PARAM_STR);         
$pStatement->bindParam(':price_descr', 
                       $_POST['carPriceDetails'], PDO::PARAM_STR);    
$pStatement->bindParam(':currency', $_POST['carCurrency'], PDO::PARAM_STR); // Parameter binding for the currency --> €     
$pStatement->bindParam(':tax', $_POST['carTax'],PDO::PARAM_INT);             
$pStatement->bindParam(':tax_descr', 
                       $_POST['carTaxDetails'], PDO::PARAM_STR);    
$pStatement->bindParam(':car_descr_long', 
                       $_POST['carDescr'], PDO::PARAM_STR);         
$pStatement->bindParam(':body_descr', 
                       $_POST['carBodyDescr'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pStatement->bindParam(':drive_train_descr', 
                       $_POST['carDriveTrainDescr'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pStatement->bindParam(':exterior_descr', 
                       $_POST['carExteriorDescr'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$pStatement->bindParam(':electronics_descr', 
                       $_POST['carElectronicsDescr'], PDO::PARAM_STR);    
$pStatement->bindParam(':safty_features_descr',   
                       $_POST['carSaftyFeaturesDescr'], PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$pStatement->bindParam(':special_features_descr',  
                       $_POST['carSpecialFeaturesDescr'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$pStatement->bindValue(':car_pic_1', null, PDO::PARAM_LOB);         
$pStatement->bindValue(':car_pic_2', null, PDO::PARAM_LOB);         
$pStatement->bindValue(':car_pic_3', null, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$pStatement->bindValue(':car_pic_4', null, PDO::PARAM_LOB);         
$pStatement->bindValue(':car_pic_5', null, PDO::PARAM_LOB);       
$pStatement->bindValue(':car_pic_6', null, PDO::PARAM_LOB);         
$pStatement->bindValue(':car_pic_7', null, PDO::PARAM_LOB);         
$pStatement->bindValue(':car_pic_8', null, PDO::PARAM_LOB);              
$pStatement->bindValue(':car_pic_9', null, PDO::PARAM_LOB);         
$pStatement->bindValue(':car_pic_10', null, PDO::PARAM_LOB);            
$pStatement->bindValue(':create_user', "Edi", PDO::PARAM_STR);      
$pStatement->bindValue(':change_user', "Edi", PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$pStatement->bindValue(':online', 
                       (empty($_POST['carOnline'])) ? "off" : "on", 
                       PDO::PARAM_STR);

$result = $pStatement->execute();
```

Would be very nice if someone could help me out of that mes.
Every help is highly appriciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it because I'm not too familiar with PDO, but where is the code that's trying to insert the Euro symbol? What column is it going into? You provided a table definition for a "cars" table that doesn't have anything in it that would appear to intend to hold a Euro symbol so I think you need to provide more code.

Comment: Thank you for reading my question.I put some more code to it. Hope it helps you.

Comment: `\x80` is surely not a Unicode codepoint and not UTF-8 either. My guess is that your sourcecode and with it your strings are not UTF-8. That said, we use `utf8_unicode_ci` without any problems with characters outside the ASCII range.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, which I don't know if it is the perfect one, but at least it is working fine!

I have added this line of code after I opened the database connection:

```
$pStatement = $db->getConnection()->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

After this Query I could insert what ever I want (e.g. ÄÜÖöäü§€%$'# etc...) and it is finally stored correctly in my table.

Well, thanks for trying to help me. I hope this solution can help someone else, who has the same problem.

I wish you all a happy new year. :-)